# In my code I am trying to update a colume type DATE but facing this issue

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datetime, sql-update

**Invalid cast from 'Int32' to 'DateTime'.Couldn't store <1> in Tdate Column.  Expected type is DateTime.**
My query is as below
**Update LogMail set Tdate= '20-Jul-15 12:00:00 AM'**

and my code is given below

```
 DateTime dtCurrTime = DateTime.Today;
 string d = dtCurrTime.ToString();

 string sQuery1 = "Update LogMail set Tdate= '"+Convert.ToDateTime(d)+"' ";
 DBInteraction.DBOperation.sConnectionString = GlobalFuncs.sConnectionString;
 sRetVal = DBOperation.ExecuteDBOperation(sQuery1, DBOperation.OperationType.UPDATE, null, ref dt);
 if (sRetVal == GlobalFuncs.SUCCESS)
 {
     Challan.EmailForPandingMaterial em=new Challan.EmailForPandingMaterial();
     em.ShowDialog(); 
     this.Hide();
 }
```

there is class DBinteraction for database and DBOperation is its method and it works fine in all other program.Please help me to find right couse of error. Thanks

Comment: Never concatenate strings to create SQL, as it's a security hazard. You should always use parameterized queries.

Comment: r u able to update the vaue directly from sql window

Comment: yah query is running fine in sql management studio

Comment: Why are you converting date time(dtCurrTime) to string and then again converting that string(d) to date time? Are you sure your update statement has no where clause?

Comment: only one row in table and one column so i don need where clause

Comment: if i put dtCurrTime directly in query still i am getting error

Comment: Is there any string alteration happening in DBOperation.ExecuteDBOperation ?? May some characters are getting replaced inside it.Debug till end of actual execution of that query may be you will find something.

Comment: First of all converting the date to a string and then converting the string back to a date does not advance anything. What is the dt parameter in your function call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `DateTime.Now`

`string sQuery1 = "Update LogMail set Tdate= '"+DateTime.Now+"' ";`

see if it generates the same error. check your datatype in Database to make sure it is of correct datatype.

Or try to save date in following date format as this is the default format in MS SQL 'yyyy-MM-dd'

Comment: i dont need datetime.now, i need to update datetime.today

Comment: It wont make any difference if you datatype in datebase is `date` it will ignore the time stamp. anyway try to use dateformat as mentioned.

Comment: so what was the exact issue. it seems `yyyy-MM-dd` solved problem

Answer (score 0):

```
// any custom format depending on your needs:
string d = dtCurrTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 

string sQuery1 = "Update LogMail set Tdate= '"+d+"' ";
```